# Syncing photos across Android devices

Tags: sync, photos

What is the best way to ensure that the photo album is synced on a daily basis between my 2 Android devices (Samsung Galaxy S5 phone and Samsung tablet)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is via Google Photos, since its allredy built into android.
https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: Note that Google Photos are *not* built-in into Android since it's under Google proprietary apps, only some devices have it preinstalled.